# can syndesis be installed on Vanila kubernetes or EKS

Tags: syndesis

I was thinking whether Syndesis can be installed on vanila Kubernetes or a EKS? all documentation and videos talk only about OpenShift/MiniShift setups while the iPaaS is mentioned as Kubernetes native.